# How to iterate nested stdClass Object?

Tags: php, soap

got this from a SOAP service, i want to get values from "codigo"

tried diff methods to access "codigo" but nothing works

```
stdClass Object
(
[return] => stdClass Object
    (
        [listOfCedulas] => stdClass Object
            (
                [cedula] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [codigo] => TR-170100-048
                            )

                        [1] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [codigo] => TR-170100-049
                            )
                        [2] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [codigo] => TR-170100-050
                            )
                     )
              )
       )
)
```

Comment: Well, what "diff" methods did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Guillermo, welcome to stack overflow, maybe it would be easier for someone to answer you if you can show them the code you tried for extracting the information you need, don't need to put the entire block, just the part that does the extraction. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Simple iteration with standard object access. Let's assume that you store the web service response in the `$response` variable.

```
$cedula = $response->return->listOfCedulas->cedula;
foreach ($cedula as $item) {
    echo $item->codigo;
}
```

However, this only works if you have ensured beforehand that the response of the web service contains exactly this data structure.

If you are using the PHP `SoapClient` class, you might want to think about and use the classmap option. You can use this option to work with value objects that correspond to the type definitions from the WSDL instead of PHP stdClass standard classes. Thus, you could achieve a certain type safety, which corresponds to the structure shown above.